# Hook to listen when RN screen changes (when navigation is called)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Using react-native navigation:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

is there a way to listen for when the view/screen changes? When nav.navigate() is called?
We could create our own wrapper and then call the hooks ourselves, but I am wonder if there is a built-in way to listen for changes to the view/screen? The goal is hide the snackbar if it's being displayed, if the user navigates.

Comment: maybe this? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to listen to screen changes:

1. Subscribe to state changes, you can read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events)
2. Using the `onStateChange` prop of the `NavigationContainer`, you can read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#onstatechange)

You could do your checks there and hide the snackbar whenever you want. The advantage it has over wrapping the `useNavigation` hook is that it will work not only with your custom hook but also with the `navigation` prop passed to all the screens within your navigator.